# Open Link depending on device

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working with an external booking system and I need different beheaviour depending on the device.

I want that it will open a new tab on mobile devices

And to open a modal box on desktop

I already have the modal box, but I dont want it to open on a mobile device. How can I implement that?

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 2):

```
window.mobileAndTabletcheck = function() {
  var check = false;
  (function(a){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino|android|ipad|playbook|silk/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4))) check = true;})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
  return check;
};
```

the above function will help you to let you know what you are using

> (mobile/tab or browser)

Answer (score 2):

you need to write media query for that

for example

```
<style>
.link{display:none;}

@media (max-width: 991px){
    .modal{
        display: none;
    }
    .link{
        display: block;
    }
}
</style>

<a href="#" class="modal"> modal </a>

<a href="#" class="link" target="_blank"> link </a>
```

Note

I have a two link in my code

I removed the mobile link on desktop view with .link{display:none;}

I show link in mobile view with .link{display:block;} and removed .modal with .modal{display:none;}

result

in desktop view you only see modal
in mobile view you only see link

Comment: what if i resize my desktop google chrome and click this link?

Comment: It will open in new tab as asked in question

Comment: he want's to open in new tab when he is on mobile device

Comment: @MumbaiWadala yes it will happen

Comment: this too won't work as you have two different button's he needs one button with multiple functionality like open on a model on desktop and open in new tab in mobile devices, hope you understand now

Comment: @MumbaiWadala refer my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can target the desired size limit with [media queries in JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_media_queries.asp). For example:

```
let mediaQuery = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 700px)')
if (mediaQuery.matches) {
  // Set URL to the anchor.
} else {
  // Configure the modal box.
}
```

Comment: you can also add this in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @VishalPanara solution, but use `any-pointer` instead of relying on screen-size.

In fact, there's a CSS media query that will include rules only for touchscreen devices:

```
@media (any-pointer: fine) {
  /*
    These rules will be applied to not-touchscreen devices
  */
}
@media (any-pointer: coarse) {
  /*
    These rules will be applied to touchscreen devices only
  */
}
```

you can check compatibility in [this page](https://caniuse.com/#search=any-pointer)